# Jquery Datetime picker Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

When I click outside the datetime picker after selecting a date and a time, it will reduce time by 1 hour.

Ex: if I selected 2.00 PM and click outside then it automatically changes the value to 1.00 PM.

How to avoid this issue ?

**HTML -**

```
<input type="text" id="txtDt">
```

**JS -**

```
$('#txtDt').datetimepicker({

       format: 'd/m/Y g:i A',
       formatTime: 'g:i A'

});
```

I got this from here - http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Comment: use date picker j query from here and don't change the query.ui file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it:

```
$('#txtDt').datetimepicker({

       format: 'd/m/Y h:i A',
       formatTime: 'h:i A',
       validateOnBlur:false

});
```